# Django templates: how to avoid empty lines with include and load?

Tags: django, django-templates, carriage-return

In a template, I use the following code:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% include "header.html" %}
{% include "top_bar.html" %}
```

But this produces several carriage returns (`\n`) as I separate every `include` and `load` by a carriage return. I don't want to concatenate inclusions like this:

```
{% include "header.html" %}{% include "top_bar.html" %}
```

Because it's unreadable.

Is there a way to avoid these generated new lines ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well after some researches, I found [this thread](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2594) where a patch is submitted and currently being reviewed. This validation step takes too much time regarding my project.

Here is [a django module](https://github.com/ldiqual/django-linestripper) I created to do that. It handles whitespaced/blank lines/empty lines just as Gary Wilson asked in the thread above.

It consists in a template loader and a middleware:

- The template loader tags the requested blank lines (those voluntary inserted by the developer)
- The middleware intercepts the `HttpResponse` and suppresses every blank line. Then, it untags the previously-requested lines and returns the cleared response

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/569/. You can also convert it to middleware to avoid additional tags in your templates.