# Django templates whitespaces ans empty characters in for loop

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a piece of django template responsible for listing some labels if there are in passed list `sources`:

```
<div id="selected-sources"  style="min-height:150px; max-height:500px">
{% for source in sources %}
<span id='{{source.0}}' class='tag_with_remove'>
<i class='icon-remove'></i>
<span class='label'>source: {{source.1}}</span>
</span>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

What results in:

```
<div id="selected-sources" style="min-height:150px; max-height:500px">

</div>
```

when `sources` is empty.

But I would like it to render like this:

```
<div id="selected-sources" style="min-height:150px; max-height:500px"></div>
```

Is it only solution to code it like this:

```
<div id="selected-sources"  style="min-height:150px; max-height:500px">{% for source in sources %}
<span id='{{source.0}}' class='tag_with_remove'><i class='icon-remove'></i><span class='label'>source: {{source.1}}</span></span>{% endfor %}</div>
```

UPDATE:
by small modification, but making code looking bit dirty I get rid of this extra line breaks:

```
<div id="selected-sources"  style="min-height:150px; max-height:500px">{% for source in sources %}
<span id='{{source.0}}' class='tag_with_remove'>
<i class='icon-remove'></i>
<span class='label'>source: {{source.1}}</span>
</span>
{% endfor %}</div>
```

Comment: probbably it is answered here if I am correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971553/django-templates-how-to-avoid-empty-lines-with-include-and-load

Comment: and this package claims being a solution https://github.com/ldiqual/django-linestripper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily get rid of all the unnecessary spaces django produces by using: `{% spaceless %}` tag see doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless

```
{% spaceless %}
<div id="selected-sources"  style="min-height:150px; max-height:500px">
{% for source in sources %}
<span id='{{source.0}}' class='tag_with_remove'>
<i class='icon-remove'></i>
<span class='label'>source: {{source.1}}</span>
</span>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endspaceless %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly, you could do something like it says [in the template docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty):

```
{% if sources %}
  <div id="selected-sources" style="min-height:150px; max-height:500px">
    {% for source in sources %}
      <span id='{{source.0}}' class='tag_with_remove'>
      <i class='icon-remove'></i>
      <span class='label'>source: {{source.1}}</span>
      </span>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% else %}
  <div id="selected-sources" style="min-height:150px; max-height:500px"></div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: phew.. ok. I was confused for a second. I haven't really come across another way of doing what you require