# css :empty - DOM state sensitive without JS is it possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css, django, django-templates

I decided to use for some list container a background image with text stating it is empty, using CSS `:empty`.

SASS:

```
div#selected-sources:empty
    background-image: url('/static/images/empty_conversions_placeholder.gif')
```

CSS:

```
div#selected-sources:empty {
  background-image: url("/static/images/empty_conversions_placeholder.gif"); }
```

It works fine when:

1) I display empty container - background is set to image

2) after adding item it disapears as expected,

BUT after removing all items - empty state - the background is not set.

JS console output:

```
$('#selected-sources').is(':empty')
false
```

UPDATE (JS part) - appending

```
$('#selected-sources')
    .append "<span id='#{ui.item.id}'
            class='tag_with_remove sources'><i class='icon-remove'></i>
            <span class='label'>#{ui.item.category}: #{ui.item.name}</span></span>"
```

UPDATE (JS part) - removing

```
$('body').on 'click', '#selected-sources i.icon-remove', () ->
    $(@).parent().remove()
```

Comment: That doesn't look like css.

Comment: It is SASS, but it is anyway "compiled" to CSS. I updated resulting CSS too.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem... http://jsfiddle.net/t6J3G/

Comment: What kind of code "removes" all the elements? Can you post it?

Comment: @zvona I updated my question with coffescript responsible for removing and adding.

Comment: What's the output of `$('#selected-sources').children().length`?

Comment: Couldn't replicate your problem either: http://jsfiddle.net/542p5/

Comment: It was django fault, what I was really not expecting to be. Thanks for help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for help.

The problem was with Django template system ass-pain with unnecesserry linebreaks (more here [Django templates whitespaces ans empty characters in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086003/django-templates-whitespaces-ans-empty-characters-in-for-loop)), which while rendering the persisted items were doing it with some line breaks, what resulted in state when "empty" DIV was not really empty have a look on screenshot from debuger of Chrome, when clicked edit HTML.

[image]

AFTER fix:

[image]

THIS SUCKS:

```
<div id="selected-sources"  style="min-height:150px; max-height:500px">
    {% for source in sources %}
        <span id='{{source.0}}' class='tag_with_remove sources'>
        <i class='icon-remove'></i>
        <span class='label'>source: {{source.1}}</span>
        </span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

THIS WORKS, but how it looks SUCKS:

```
<div id="selected-sources"  style="min-height:150px; max-height:500px">{% for source in sources %}<span id='{{source.0}}' class='tag_with_remove sources'><i class='icon-remove'></i><span class='label'>source: {{source.1}}</span></span>{% endfor %}</div>
```